# What is the best way to format a date in JSON for Mongo DB storage

Tags: ruby, json, mongodb

I have a date with a time. I'm using ruby, but the language shouldn't matter.

d = "2010-04-01 13:00:00"

What is the best way to format this date for Mongo DB?  By 'best' I mean, is there a certain format I could use where Mongo would recognize it as a date and might give me more-advanced filtering optons?

ie: If formatted correctly, could I ask Mongo to return all records whose month is '04'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to format dates at all;  dates are a supported data type.  Each client driver should support dates through their standard date type, including the [ruby one](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/BSON#BSON-Ruby).

For advanced queries like your example, you can use a [javascript expression](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-JavascriptExpressionsand%7B%7B%24where%7D%7D) for the find specifier:

```
{"$where": "this.date.getMonth() == 3"}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, since it's far from obvious, the reason it says 3 instead of 4 in the code example above is that for some mysterious reason the months go from 0 to 11 in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

In ruby you should use a Time instance, which will get stored as the BSON datetime type. You could use a $where clause like Coady mentions, but will be better to do a range query with $lt and $gt - less overhead and can leverage an index.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like relying on mongo Date objects. I think Mongo is slower with 'date' objects than it is with other data types (such as integers).

I tend to use integers (if you need timezone, have a tz field too, then  you have localized time):

```
document = {:some_timestamp => Time.now.to_i}
@collection.find({'some_timestamp' => {'$gte' => Time.now.to_i}})
```

Sometimes I just use the timestamp built into the BSON::ObjectId's:

```
id = BSON::ObjectId.from_time(Time.now)
@collection.find({'_id' => {'$lte' => id}})
```